# If $p$ is a fixed point, does $\forall x\in U \setminus\{p\}: f(x)\neq p$ hold?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, derivatives

Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb R, \mathbb R), f(p)=p, f'(p)=0,$ and $f''(p)\neq 0$. I showed that there is a neighborhood $U$ of $a$ such that the fixed-point iteration $x_{k+1}:=f(x_k)$ converges to $p$. Then I was asked to prove a statement about $$\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{|p-x_{k+1}|}{|p-x_k|^2}.$$ Which I also did but then I asked myself the following:

How do we know that the sequence under the limit is defined? I.e. how can we show that $$\forall x\in U \setminus\{p\}: f(x)\neq p$$

I've tried showing that there is such an $U$ that $f$ is injective on $U$ yet it clearly won't work because e.g. $f(x)=x^2, p=0$ satisfy the setup yet there is no neighborhood of $p=0$ in which $f(x)=x^2$ is injective.

Comment: Usually one picks a neighbourhood where $f(p) \neq p$, this can be done since $f''(p) \neq 0$ (use Taylor's theorem). You are trying to show that the convergence is quadratic, if you happened to hit the actual fixed point, then the convergence is (much) better than quadratic :-).

Comment: @copper.hat: could you clarify what you mean by "a neighbourhood where $f(p)≠p$"?

Comment: The assumptions mean that $f(x) = f(p) + {1 \over 2}\int_p^x f''(t)(x-t)dt$, and for $x$ close to $p$ we have $\int_p^x f''(t)(x-t)dt \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f''(p) > 0.$ Since $f\in C^2, f''> 0$ in $I = (p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0.$ This implies $f'$ is strictly increasing in $I.$ Since $f'(p) = 0,$ this tells us $f'< 0$ in $(p-\epsilon, p),\, f'> 0$ in $(p, p+\epsilon).$ Thus $f$ is strictly decreasing in $(p-\epsilon, p),$ and $f$ is strictly increasing in $(p, p+\epsilon).$ Thus $f(x)\ne p$ in $I\setminus \{p\}.$ The argument is the same if $f''(p) < 0.$